# Change font-color of TextField inside MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've a problem to change the font-color of a TextField after it has been added as a child to a MovieClip.

My code:

```
var btn:MovieClip = new MovieClip();        
// other code for button

var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.size = 12;
tf.bold = true;
tf.font = "Arial"
tf.color = 0x000000;

var capt:TextField = new TextField();
capt.defaultTextFormat = tf;
capt.width = 200;
capt.height = 50;
capt.text = "Test";
capt.y = 20;
capt.x = 20;
capt.border = false;
capt.selectable = false;    

btn.addChild(capt);

// .....
```

How can I Change the font-color after the last line?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking for [TextField.setTextFormat()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#setTextFormat%28%29). You can either adjust your original `TextFormat` or just make a whole new one.

```
tf.color = 0xFF0000;
capt.setTextFormat(tf);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Is it possible to call "setTextFormat" through btn. ?

btn.capt.setTextFormat(tf) doesn't work.

The reason I am asking is, that I'm creating the buttons dynamically. After btn.addChild(capt) i'm saving all buttons in an array.

Comment: Not easily. You'd be better off saving the TextFields to an array as well, or to a [Dictionary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html) with the buttons as the keys.

Comment: Actually it is easy, as Apocalyptic0n3 shows in their answer. I thought you had `SimpleButton`s for some reason. You can either keep a reference to the `TextField`s or just find them again like that.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the `TextField` falls out of scope after that last line (you don't show enough to know if it does or not), you'll need to loop through the button to get the TextField and do it from there.

```
var i:uint;
var l:uint = btn.numChildren; //numChildren and length are 'heavy' getters, never use them as restrictors in a loop
for ( i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
    var cur:DisplayObject = btn.getChildAt( i );
    if ( cur is TextField ) {
        ( cur as TextField ).setTextFormat( /*set new TextFormat in here*/);
        break;
    }
}
```

That assumes there is only the single TextField, of course. If there are multiple, I would extend MovieClip and add a public property for the value you want to change.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just use the textColor property of a textfield:

```
capt.textColor = 0xFF0000;
```