# How to change the text color in NumericStepper

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, numericstepper

I seriously cannot find a way to simply change the text color of a NumericStepper. Is it event possible?

Comment: I think your question has been answered in another thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549598/change-font-color-of-textfield-inside-movieclip

Comment: is it an mx or spark NumericStepper? is it a mobile project?

Answer (score 1):

Please use 'setStyle' method for text color:

Please read this post : [Link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_08.html)

Comment: I tried `this.setStyle("color", 0x000000); ` and `this.setStyle("color", "black");` and it didn't word

Comment: Please read the post its gives the proper initialization of get and set style like this:  public function initApp():void {
        StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration("Button").
            setStyle("themeColor",0x6666CC);
        StyleManager.getStyleDeclaration("Button").
            setStyle("color","Blue");
     }

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<input type="text" value="something" onclick="this.value='';this.style.color='red';" />
```