# How do I set the color of a NumericStepper?

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark, numericstepper

I have already looked at this question:[How to change the text color in NumericStepper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021844/how-to-change-the-text-color-in-numericstepper) the link referenced is broken.

I have the following code:

```
var sdAdopt:NumericStepper = sdAdoptGroup.getChildAt(year) as NumericStepper;
sdAdopt.textDisplay.setStyle("color","red");
```

it does not work.

I have also tried

```
sdAdopt.setStyle("color", 0xFF0000);
```

I have also tried using a textFormatter object. Nothing has worked. What is going on?

Comment: if you're using spark NumericStepper, you can easily customize it by creating (changing default) custom skin. Example: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS0DD82E88-6A07-4b57-BD24-02661DBF32EA.html

Answer (score 0):

To Change the colour of the text just use setStyle like so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function click(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                ns.textDisplay.setStyle("color", 0xFF0000);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:NumericStepper id="ns"/>
    <s:Button click="click(event)" label="Change Color" />
</s:Application>
```

I'm not sure why your sample code is using year in the call to getChildAt.